# Fresnel integral

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

Can the following integral be performed in Mathematica?

```
Assuming[Element[{a, b}, Reals] && (Abs[a] > 0 || Abs[b] > 0) && 
r > 0, Integrate[Exp[I*k*(p^2 + q^2)^(1/2)]*Exp[I*(a*p + b*q)], 
Element[{p, q}, Disk[{0, 0}, r]]] // FunctionExpand]
```

Comment: If you change to polar coordinates you can reduce it to `Integrate[
 2 E^(I k rr) \[Pi] rr BesselJ[0, Sqrt[a^2 + b^2] rr], {rr, 0, r}]`, but it chokes on that one.  Maybe someone can take from there.

Comment: Following @MichaelE2, you could then do a series expansion of `BesselJ`.  The infinite sum might give you something useful, or depending on the relative size of `a`, `b` and `r` you might find that a few  terms are sufficient.